# 'Find' function working incorrectly, have tried floating point accuracy resolution

Tags: matlab, floating-accuracy

I have vertically concatenated files from my directory into a matrix that is about 60000 x 15 in size (verified).

```
d=dir('*.log');
n=length(d);
data=[];
for k=1:n
    data{k}=importdata(d(k).name);
end
total=[];
for k=1:n
    total=[total;data{n}];
end
```

I am using a the following 32-iteration loop and the 'Find" function to locate row numbers where the final column is an integer corresponding to the integer iteration of the loop:

```
for i=1:32
    v=[];
    vn=[];
    [v,vn]=find(abs(fix(i)-fix(total))<eps);
    g=length(v)
end
```

I have tried to account for the floating point accuracy by using 'fix' on values of 'i' and values from matrix 'total', in addition to taking their absolute difference and checking it to be less than a tolerance of 'eps' (floating-point relative accuracy function), up to a tolerance of .99.

The 'Find' function is not working correctly.  It is only working for certain integers (although it should be locating all of them (1-32)), and for the integers it does find the values are incomplete.

What is the problem here? If 'Find' is inadequate for this purpose, what is a suitable alternative?

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that `find` is working just fine and you misunderstand how it works. It may be worth backing up and telling us what you're actually trying to do because it isn't clear.

Comment: Column 15 of the matrix is the only column with integer values between 1-32, hence, the find function should return vector 'v' with row numbers attributed to that particular integer in question (vn is irrelevant).  The output shows me that the length of v is zero for many integers for which it should not be zero.  I need to use the vector 'v' to locate the row numbers, from which i can take corresponding data from a different column in matrix 'total'.  Does that clear things up?

Comment: You might want to write `total(:)` as `total` is 60000 x 15. Also, you can use [cell2mat](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) in the first code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a lot of zeros because you are looking not just at the 15th column of `data` but *the entire data matrix* so you are going to have a lot of non-integers.

Also, you're using `fix` on both numbers and since floating point errors can cause the number to be slightly above *and* below the desired integer, this will cause the ones that are below to round *down* an integer lower than what you'd expect. You should use `round` to round to the nearest integer instead.

Rather than using `find` to do this, I would use simple boolean logic to determine the value of the last column

```
for k = 1:32
    % Compare column 15 to the current index
    matches = abs(total(:,end) - k) < eps;

    % Do stuff with these matches
    g = sum(matches);   % Count the matches
end
```

Depending on what you want to actually do with the data, you may be able to use the last column as an input to `accumarray` to perform an operation on each group.

As a side note, you can replace the first chunk of code with

```
d = dir('*.log');

data = cellfun(@importdata, {d.name}, 'UniformOutput', false);
total = cat(1, data{:});
```

Comment: the solution you posted in the first code block does not work for integers: 2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,16,17,20,23,25,26,29,30,31

Comment: I used your version of the concatenation, as well as the floating-point-friendly version for the loop, looks like it worked.  much appreciated